# Повороты в openGL

Tags: opengl

Я хочу повернуть модель вокруг её оси, а не вокруг мировых осей. Можно ли это сделать не перенося модель? Я нашёл статью про quaternion, но у моя модель всё равно поворачивается вокруг мировых осей. Возможно я неправильно понял статью. Вот мой код:

```
void Model::rotateAroundModelAxis(vec3 EulerAngles)
{
    quat quaternion = quat(EulerAngles);
    rotationMatrix = mat4_cast(quaternion);
}

mat4 Model::ModelMatrix()
{
    return translationMatrix * rotationMatrix * scaleMatrix;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Матрица поворота работает относительно начала координат. Поэтому модель изначально нужно строить вокруг её центра вращения и только в самом конце translationMatrix переносит модель в нужное место в мире)

MVP:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Model Matrix — это `translationMatrix * rotationMatrix * scaleMatrix` (в обратном порядке)
View Matrix - это направление и ориентация камеры(LookAt)
Projection Matrix - искажение перспективы

[Неплохой туториал](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/ru/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/)

Comment: На этом же сайте есть вот эта статья http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/ru/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-17-quaternions/ . Я пытаюсь с ней разобраться

Comment: Кватернионы - всего лишь другой способ задать матрицу поворота

Comment: Смена центра вращения описана в пункте `How do I apply a rotation to a point?`, однако это на самом деле просто предварительный перенос.